# Problem of re-rendering useEffect with watch all fields using React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I using a lib React Hook Form for a form with checkboxes inputs. I don't understand whats wrong in this code. This code re-render a useEffect with dependency. This behavior not verified when a just try render a single checkbox input. Someone have a idea, for use a map function to render multiple inputs, without this re-render ?

I create a sandbox with this code https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-watch-c9xgu?file=/src/index.js

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Hi, press the checkboxes render by js map function called twice by the useEffect.

Comment: update the lib to the latest version, it will fix your problem.
see  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-watch-forked-d1d92?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks zb22, this solve the problem

Answer (score 13):

You are using react-hook-form watch method. this method will re-render at the root level of the app whenever a field value is changed.

for better performance you can use useWatch instead, it will only re-render at the component level.

Please have a look at the official docs [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch)